# Gradle Fails to Compile Basic Scala Project

Tags: scala, gradle

I cannot seem to get gradle to properly compile a simple Scala project. The directory looks like:

```
.
├── build.gradle
└── src
    └── Main.scala
```

The `build.gradle` is simply:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

sourceSets {
    main {
        scala {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
```

It fails with this charming little error:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileScala'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:179)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:232)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:138)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:247)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.executeTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:30)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:130)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:137)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method withInputStream() on null object
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AntBuilderDelegate.taskdef(DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder.groovy:136)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.AntScalaCompiler$_execute_closure1.doCall(AntScalaCompiler.groovy:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:58)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$configure.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder.execute(DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder.groovy:112)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.IsolatedAntBuilder$execute.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.AntScalaCompiler.execute(AntScalaCompiler.groovy:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.AntScalaCompiler.execute(AntScalaCompiler.groovy)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.DefaultScalaJavaJointCompiler.execute(DefaultScalaJavaJointCompiler.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.DefaultScalaJavaJointCompiler.execute(DefaultScalaJavaJointCompiler.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.DelegatingScalaCompiler.execute(DelegatingScalaCompiler.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.DelegatingScalaCompiler.execute(DelegatingScalaCompiler.java:22)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:23)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.scala.ScalaCompile.compile(ScalaCompile.java:131)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:122)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.scala.ScalaCompile_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:161)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:156)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:472)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:461)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:60)
        ... 57 more


BUILD FAILED
```

My `gradle --version` is:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Tuesday, November 20, 2012 11:37:38 AM UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.6.0_24 (Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.0-b12)
OS: Linux 3.2.0-29-generic amd64
```

What in the world is going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't declared which Scala version to use, as shown in the docs and samples. (The error message is fixed in the upcoming Gradle 1.4.)

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    scalaTools "org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.9.2"
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.2"
}
```

Comment: After adding that, now I'm getting "Could not find method scala() for arguments [org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.9.2] on root project 'grad'".

Comment: Right, it's `scalaTools` (fixed). Gradle 1.4 will infer this automatically from the `compile` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on Gradle 2.1. (Although I didn't get the same error, Google found this for me.) I had a "Caused by: : Compilation failed because of an internal compiler error; see the error output for details." error, which didn't tell me anything heh.

I didn't see [anything on the documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html) to indicate that I needed to use scalaTools or anything like that.

I ended up turning off the ant based compilation to use the TypeSafe Zinc compiler instead

```
tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    scalaCompileOptions.useAnt = false
}
```